# How to merge cellcontents from one book to another

Tags: excel, vba

I need some content in different columns and cells from workbook 1 to be copied in workbook 2.

Here's an example:

```
Workbook1.Worksheets("sheet25").Range("B2:AA2")
```

For each value in those cells it needs to contain 2 columns from the same workbook and sheet:
e.g. B2 value needs column `A9:EndOfValue + B9:EndOfValue`.

This needs to be copied into `workbook2.Sheet1("Sheet1").Range("A2:EndofValue")`
This starts again when the code comes in column C2 of workbook1 and so on for all values in workbook 2 up to the last one (AA2).

I would think about using a `for each` loop but I've read that this leaves a lot of dirt with big files when closing (mine is very big! like 35000 lines that will be multiplied after copying with 26 and 100!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution for your question. As far as I gathered from your description, the sum of column A and column B are combined for a single result that is returned in, say, cell A1 of the new workbook, then B1 for the next two columns, etc. - I used 26 columns with the numbers 1 to 35000 for the purpose. I've also assumed that your data is 35000 rows long and 26 rows wide. Using nested loops is the option I have, but I've employed a dynamic array that calculates the sum  of columns A and B, B and C, C and D and so on, until it reaches the end.

The logic of the program establishes the horizontal and vertical extent of the data, using xlRight and xlUp, respectively. The nested loops, in turn, have three levels. The outermost determines the successive cells in the new sheet, where the total sums are outputted, the second level goes through each column with data and the last level limits the processing to the last row of data.

The dynamic array is going to increase to 35000 units each time a column is processed. Every array item is the sum of the active cell in the column and the one next to it. At the end of each cycle, the array and the value that outputs the sum are zeroed out, before the next column is analyzed.

For the sake of the example, I've used Sheet1 and Sheet2 of the same file, but for your purposes, it would be as easy as creating a workbook variable (e.g. x.workbooks.add) and setting it as the output destination.

Unfortunately, the program does take a while to execute, but my machine does date from the time Lehman Brothers was still relevant.

To with with the code, and comments are integrated:

```
Sub summing_bigdata()

Dim n As Double, a As Double, b As Double
Dim Z As Integer
Dim arr_s() As Variant
Dim lstcl As Variant, lstcl2 As Variant

'establish the limits of the data
lstcl = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
lstcl2 = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column


'establish successive output columns
For Z = 1 To lstcl2
    'looping through each column of data
    For a = 1 To lstcl2
        'looping through each row of data
        For n = 1 To lstcl

            'preserve the size of the array at each pass to prevent overwriting previous data
            ReDim Preserve arr_s(n)

            'fill each array item with the sum of each cell in the column and the cell next to it
            arr_s(n) = Cells(n, a).Value + Cells(n, a).Offset(0, 1).Value

         Next

    'add all the elements of the array into b
    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr_s)

    'output b in the new sheet/file
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, Z) = b

    Next

    'reset the value of b and the array for the next column to be analyzed
    b = 0
    Erase arr_s

Next

End Sub
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wauw! Thanks a lot for your time and explanation. But I'm so sorry! I've made a little mistake apparently. It's not the total of the two columns that needs to be in the new column in book two. I just need those two columns copied in a column each in book two. Nevertheless, I think I will be able to use your loops to contribute to mine. Again, thanks a lot! Cheers.